# Redux Testing - getState() TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDateIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript, redux

I have been looking at Testing React + Redux using the .Net Core example provided with visual studio.
I'm not sure if I have gone down completely the wrong path, but I am trying to test one of the actions that have been written to generate weather data. I am looking at this action:

```
export const actionCreators = {
    requestWeatherForecasts: (startDateIndex) => async (dispatch, getState) => {

        if (startDateIndex === getState().weatherForecasts.startDateIndex) {
            // Don't issue a duplicate request (we already have or are loading the requested data)
            return;
        }


        dispatch({ type: requestWeatherForecastsType, startDateIndex });

        const url = `api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts?startDateIndex=${startDateIndex}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const forecasts = await response.json();
        dispatch({ type: receiveWeatherForecastsType, startDateIndex, forecasts });
    }
};
```

When I have been testing this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDateIndex' of undefined
```

I under stand that this is caused by the check at the start of the action but I can't seem to figure out why the test keeps failing when it reaches the line. Here is the full code for my test:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import expect from 'expect';
import { actionCreators } from './WeatherForecasts';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
let state = { startDateIndex: 5, forecasts: [], isLoading: false };
const store = mockStore(() => state);

describe('WeatherForecasts Actions', () => {

    afterEach(function () {
        fetchMock.restore();
    });   

    it('Creates a Request and a Receive signal', () => {
        fetchMock.get('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts?startDateIndex=0', {
            body: [{ "dateFormatted": "12/12/2018", "temperatureC": 6, "summary": "Warm", "temperatureF": 42 }, { "dateFormatted": "13/12/2018", "temperatureC": -17, "summary": "Scorching", "temperatureF": 2 }, { "dateFormatted": "14/12/2018", "temperatureC": 10, "summary": "Scorching", "temperatureF": 49 }, { "dateFormatted": "15/12/2018", "temperatureC": 30, "summary": "Hot", "temperatureF": 85 }, { "dateFormatted": "16/12/2018", "temperatureC": -4, "summary": "Balmy", "temperatureF": 25 }],
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        })

        const expectedActions = [
            { type: "REQUEST_WEATHER_FORECASTS", startDateIndex: 0},
            { type: "RECEIVE_WEATHER_FORECASTS", startDateIndex: 0, forecasts: [{ "dateFormatted": "12/12/2018", "temperatureC": 6, "summary": "Warm", "temperatureF": 42 }, { "dateFormatted": "13/12/2018", "temperatureC": -17, "summary": "Scorching", "temperatureF": 2 }, { "dateFormatted": "14/12/2018", "temperatureC": 10, "summary": "Scorching", "temperatureF": 49 }, { "dateFormatted": "15/12/2018", "temperatureC": 30, "summary": "Hot", "temperatureF": 85 }, { "dateFormatted": "16/12/2018", "temperatureC": -4, "summary": "Balmy", "temperatureF": 25 }] }
        ];    
        const startDateIndex = 0;

        return store.dispatch(actionCreators.requestWeatherForecasts(startDateIndex)).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });
    });
});
```

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action creator is assuming the state has a `weatherForecasts` property. It probably *would* have that in real production code, but in your tests where you set up a fake state for testing purposes, there is no `weatherForecasts` property. Instead, the relevant data lives at the top level of the state, without a namespace.

Here are two possible solutions:

A. Remove the incorrect assumption of the `weatherForecasts` namespace from the action creator. This would be my preferred solution since it slightly simplifies things.

```
if (startDateIndex === getState().startDateIndex) {
```

B. Add the namespace to the state when creating it, to match the existing assumptions of the action creator.

```
let state = { weatherForecasts : { startDateIndex: 5, forecasts: [], isLoading: false } };
```

Comment: Thanks for this Seth! I ended up looking at both methods but ultimately had to use the second solution as the first solution caused the application to fetch the data continuously.